# Physics/Game Engine in C++ for mobile app

Tags: c++, android, ios, game-development

First post so be gentle.

I am a junior seeking a Comp Sci major and was looking into making a mobile game. I wanted to use this for my thesis project next year, and possibly a way to pay back college loans. I do know how to make android apps since I have done some for a class.

My idea is to make a shuffle board game using my own physics engine in C++. Obviously this is a huge undertaking, but I think it will look pretty good on my resume.

I need help understanding how to connect my C++ engine to an android application. Should I code the whole app in C++, or how do I use the Android SDK to import this?

How would I go about making graphics for the game? Any good programs? I might have this covered since YouTube is a good starting point; just looking for some suggestions. This is my weakest point since I am not heavily invested in graphic design, but I have dabbled in some photoshop before.

Since I want to use c++ for the engine, would this be pretty easy to port over to iOS?

Also, would I rather make a physics or game engine in this circumstance? And what would be my first step.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important).** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sorry that you were given bad advice on SO to re-ask this question here on Programmers.  Your question is too broad to be meaningfully answered.  If you were to focus your question on specific conceptual problems you are encountering, it may be more on-topic.

Comment: Seriousy? I was told to come here to get a better response. I don't understand how its too broad? I'm lookin for opinions on how to get started and what the best way to get a mobile game with a engine written in C++. Yet, such a simple opinion is hard to get.

Comment: "A simple opinion is hard to get" on this site, because that's not what it is intended for. The site prefers questions that can be answered factually, like: "This is what I'm doing and this is the (bad) result I'm getting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MichaelGulik sorry, you were given bad advice. Asking "how do I get started" or "what project should I work on" is very broad, tends to be subjective, and is not what Stack Exchange is about.

Comment: Sooooooo then what other website is there to ask questions about coding?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I wanted to use this for my thesis project next year, [...]

Using a mobile game for your thesis is non-trivial (you will probably need your project's documentation to include game theory and what not (I think this is how Tetris was invented). Good luck!

> [...] and possibly a way to pay back college loans.

Steps:

1. write game
2. ???
3. proffit

In short, do not make a plan that relies on the financial success of your game. It is very probable your game will not achieve financial success of any kind. Also, if you solve step 2 above, please let us know ;)

> My idea is to make a shuffle board game using my own physics engine in C++. Obviously this is a huge undertaking, but I think it will look pretty good on my resume.

Creating a physics engine sounds ... big. Very big! (as in "five years of effort to get stability and feature completeness" big).

> I need help understanding how to connect my C++ engine to an android application.

Create a library in C++, export it's interface as JNI, create Dalvik application that uses said interface; rinse, repeat; Basically, you would have a Dalvik application that uses internal libraries (like all other applications that use libraries).

> Should I code the whole app in C++, or how do I use the Android SDK to import this?

Your call!

> Since I want to use c++ for the engine, would this be pretty easy to port over to iOS?

Not by itself, no. To achieve portability you need to depend on the same libraries on both systems. You could make the application easier to port to iOS, by choosing what libraries to use based on how available they are on both systems, but getting it to "pretty easy to port" will probably take a lot of effort.

> Also, would I rather make a physics or game engine in this circumstance? And what would be my first step.

Your first step should probably be to check out existing game/physics engines and their capabilities, and choose an existing one (which is fine, unless you plan your thesis to be on physics engines - then you should write your own).